Tuned Gain Stage
I have a problem. Why the gain in low frequency is -gm1Rp?
From my knowledge, when we do the small signal model, we short the inductor and open the capacitor.
Therefore, gain of LC oscillator should be 0.
How come that the gain is -gm1Rp?
Thanks a lot

Reference: Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit Design, 2nd Edition, P621

Are they asking about the exact case where $X_\text{L}=X_\text{C}$?

Probably
However, L and C is small enough that it should have a high frequency to have the biggest output impedance.
https://imgur.com/1IYH2Yo

Yeah. That's exactly the case they are asking about, where $sL=\frac1{sC}$.

Oh I misunderstood the sentence. Thanks a lot

That is the correct gain, at resonance, for the small-signal and low-frequency transistor model.
The small signal model uses the general transistor model, linearized around the operating point.  You seem to be thinking of the DC equivalent circuit, where inductors are shorted and capacitors are opened, and at DC, the gain of this circuit is zero.
